# Cordova XCode Project Build Error

Tags: xcode, plugins, cordova

When I am trying to build my project in XCode I am getting following error for ChildBrowser Plugin and PDF Viewer Plugins. Does anyone have idea for the same?

[image]

Thanks,
Ankit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you follwed the plugin instructions?

childbrowser
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/ChildBrowser

pdf
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/PDFViewer